# logstash Unknown setting 'convert' for csv {:level=>:error}

Tags: date, csv, logstash

I'm trying to import a CSV file into Elastic Search using Logstash. Here is my config file

```
input {
        file    {
                path => "c:/Elkwin_Free_x64/input/export.csv"
                start_position => beginning
        }
}
filter {
        csv {
                columns => [
                        "Date",
                        "Transaction",
                        "Name",
                        "Memo",
                        "Amount"
                ]
                separator => ","
                convert => {"Date" => "date"}
        }
}
output {
        elasticsearch {
                action => "index"
                host => "localhost"
                index => "USB-%{+YYYY.MM}"
                workers => 1
        }

        stdout {
                codec => rubydebug
        }
}
```

I would like the "Date" column to get converted to a "date" type instead of a "string". However, when I run logstash, I get the following error message

```
 c:\Elkwin_Free_x64\logstash\bin>logstash -f "C:\Elkwin_Free_x64\logstash\conf\logstash.conf
 io/console not supported; tty will not be manipulated
 Unknown setting 'convert' for csv {:level=>:error}
 Error: Something is wrong with your configuration.
 You may be interested in the '--configtest' flag which you can
 use to validate logstash's configuration before you choose
 to restart a running system.
```

Please suggest what change I've to make.

Answer (score 2):

The `csv/convert` setting only appeared in Logstash 2.2, so if you're using an older version of Logstash that's the reason it is complaining.

You can either upgrade to Logstash 2.2, 2.3 or preferably 2.4 or use the [`date` filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/2.4/plugins-filters-date.html) instead like this (note that the [`mutate/convert`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/2.4/plugins-filters-mutate.html#plugins-filters-mutate-convert) filter doesn't support date conversion):

```
filter {
        csv {
                columns => [
                        "Date",
                        "Transaction",
                        "Name",
                        "Memo",
                        "Amount"
                ]
                separator => ","
        }
        date {
            match => ["Date", "ISO8601", "d/m/yyyy"]
            target => "Date"
        }
}
```

PS: I've picked `ISO8601` but make sure that the [date format](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/2.4/plugins-filters-date.html#plugins-filters-date-match) matches what you have in your `Date` field.

Comment: Val - thanks for your response. I've not been successful with my goal still. I'm using all latest versions now - elasticsearch 2.4.0, logstash 2.4.0, and kibana 4.6.1. I've a CSV file that has a date field and it has values like 9/2/2016, 9/9/2016 etc. I wan to use this field as the event timestamp instead of the one that logstash is generating. I'm using convert in CSV filter and then date filter to get a timestamp -  date {
  match => ["Date", "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss+SSSS"] }. However, I'm getting an exception Invalid format: \"9/9/2016\" is malformed at \"9/2016\". Appreciate your left.